# Using OpenIDConnect for Facebook

Tags: asp.net, facebook, openid-connect

I am trying to build an **MVC WebApp supporting multiple external providers using Google, Facebook, Microsoft and Twitter**. So far with help from multiple online articles, I have succeeded in building a simple cookie based authentication scheme along with Google as authentication provider. Somehow the same logic for adding Facebook is not working. I am struggling with the *FacebookOptions* for **Authority** as I it keeps redirecting me to a Facebook page OAuth page which states "Sorry, something went wrong"
[image: Facebook Error]

Here is how I defined my **AddAuthentication** method in **Program.cs**

```
    {
        options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    })
    .AddCookie(options =>
    {
        options.LoginPath = new PathString("/login");
        options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/denied");
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect("google", googleOIDOptions =>
    {
        string gClientId = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Google:ClientId").Value;
        string gClientPwd = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Google:ClientSecret").Value;
        string gPath = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Google:CallbackPath").Value;
        
        googleOIDOptions.Authority = "https://accounts.google.com";
        googleOIDOptions.ClientId = gClientId;
        googleOIDOptions.ClientSecret = gClientPwd;
        googleOIDOptions.CallbackPath = gPath;
        googleOIDOptions.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/google-signout";
    })
    .AddOpenIdConnect("facebook", fbOIDOptions =>
    {
        string fbClientId = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Facebook:ClientId").Value;
        string fbClientPwd = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Facebook:ClientSecret").Value;
        string fbPath = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Facebook:CallbackPath").Value;

        fbOIDOptions.Authority = "https://www.facebook.com"; //"https://www.facebook.com/v16.0/dialog/oauth"; //;
        //fbOIDOptions.Authority = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth"; 
        fbOIDOptions.ClientId = fbClientId;
        fbOIDOptions.ClientSecret = fbClientPwd;
        fbOIDOptions.AccessDeniedPath = "/denied";
        //fbOIDOptions.CallbackPath = fbPath;
        //fbOIDOptions.SignedOutCallbackPath = "/facebook-signout";
        //fbOIDOptions.Scope.Add("email");
        //fbOIDOptions.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.Code;
        //fbOIDOptions.SaveTokens = true; 
    });
```

In my **HomeController.cs** I defined a common method to intake multiple providers as follows,

```
[HttpGet("login/{provider}")]
    public IActionResult LoginExternal([FromRoute] string provider, [FromQuery] string returnUrl)
    {
        if (User != null && User.Identities.Any(identity => identity.IsAuthenticated))
        {
            RedirectToAction("", "Home");
        }

        returnUrl = string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) ? "/" : returnUrl;
        var authenticationProperties = new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = returnUrl };

        return new ChallengeResult(provider, authenticationProperties);
    }
```

If you check the developer console I see page redirection as shown below as per the HTTP 302 code,
[image: Facebook login navigated to error page] but when I try to investigate further with client_id information passed it seems page has been permanently redirected as per the HTTP 301 error code to
*https://facebook.com/dialog/oauth/?client_id=490605846573318&redirect_uri=https://localhost:7081/signin-oidc&response_type=id_token&scope=openid profile&response_mode=form_post&nonce=638109963739908338.ZWY0ZmM3NzMtNTM4Yy00YmVjLWJkOWEtYjY2NTMxZjRmYzNjZjg5NDRiYjQtNWU5Mi00NDI2LTg0NTQtYzVjZTAwM2FhMjdi&state=CfDJ8JX6wl_svOBCsCJLieG3tWwPbNfc9_vXYgF9hS8kM6eaFOb88LT-Baza9C3f5o-tn-7A5NYsI-rSTBiikzos3As_tkJxOrFzNGTWIgxmxdceVHim_mWudlhH-4fNCdCG2wZmWZPxHS7ES3FkoryXRSJ7wbVvIY3P4fDTpUsnJDfdl_z7i37VHkLighOHAfOXkKBAPYQTgibKJtd7WA0JC4V6j4_3xjNjeN12pBNtj0VGIeABxwwjQanAoiKb5yswfA73nr8ryEuF32Ikx4TE_s3_Mls7lIPrEWiRDEW5f7VhD246WhxKKEcinvUaMocGMA&x-client-SKU=ID_NETSTANDARD2_0&x-client-ver=6.15.1.0*

After the above step the [image: encrypted_query_string page is showing HTTP 500 error]
I am not able to get what is causing this internal server error. Any clue or help is highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You got a `&scope=openid profile` in there, and as far as I know that is not a scope Facebook's OAuth supports. In fact, when I try and add that permission to the scopes of an otherwise valid login dialog call, I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

To access Facebook, a better approach is to replace AddOpenIdConnect with AddFaceBook(), that is more optimized for just Facebook authentication.

```
services.AddAuthentication().AddFacebook(facebookOptions =>
    {
        facebookOptions.AppId = configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppId"];
        facebookOptions.AppSecret = configuration["Authentication:Facebook:AppSecret"];
    });
```

In theory AddOpenIDConnect should work, but AddFaceBook will make your life easier.

AddFaceBook is found in [this](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook) NuGet package.

For more details, see [Facebook external login setup in ASP.NET Core
7.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/social/facebook-logins?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: While I am aware of AddFacebook() authentication approach I was hoping if OpenIdConnect would work for Facebook. Would you have any clue why the same wouldn't work when it works efficiently for Google?

Comment: I am, sure you can make it work with OpenIDConnect and Facebook as well, but I guess they have some special thing that is needed to make it work. I would compare the source for AddFaceBook and AddOpenIDConnect here https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/main/src/Security/Authentication to see what's actually different.

Comment: Also, I guess it is because Facebook is OAuth compliant and not OpenID-connect compliant. The AddFaceBook handler is inherited from the OAuthHandler baseclass, while AddOpenIDConnect is inherited from  RemoteAuthenticationHandler and hence more advanced.... For example the FacebookHandler seems not to deal with ID-tokens for example.

Does that answer your question?